# Passing binding value from Input element to Model through ngModel

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. Facing problem to pass the input value to my database model. Based on the account id, the firstname from database is binding to Input element. but the same input value(AccountName) not able to pass to model. where i am doing wrong.Need suggestion.

In html template --

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup.enter)="checkAccount($event)" [(ngModel)]="modelName.AccountId">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" value={{AccountName}} readonly [(ngModel)]="modelName.AccountName">
```

In Component:

```
  checkAccount(event:any){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
          this.customerService.getCustomer({customer_id: Number(event.target.value)}).subscribe(
            data => {
              if (data){
                this.AccountName = data.firstname;
            }else{
              alert("No Account Found");
            }
            }
          );
        }else{
        }
     }
```

I am getting  {{modelName | json}} output as {"AccountId": "6" }.
Expecting account name should be available in my Model. Not able to pass AccountName to model in insert into database.

Comment: Remove `value={{AccountName}}` from HTML. Why are you not directly passing `modelName.AccountName` to Database ? Why are you creating a new variable for this purpose ? can u explain that

Comment: The reason i put value={{AccountName}} to  display the account name in html form. any other suggestion to display AccountName in html?

Comment: how to pass modelName.AccountName directly to database ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Shashank....it works and finally i added to database as well.

Comment: Great ! Please mark it as an answer so that others can find it helpful as well and feel free to upvote as well

Comment: saroj, as I provided the answer by putting my time into it. it would really makes sense if you provide your input to appreciate my effort

Answer (score 0):

While you are using [(ngModel)] you need to add property name to your tag :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="account-id" (keyup.enter)="checkAccount($event)" [(ngModel)]="modelName.AccountId">
```

I think you don't need to value={{AccountName}} ngModel is enough to show your data it's the two-way binding concept.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you just want to show "AccountName" as readonly field after you get value from :

```
this.AccountName = data.firstname;
```

Try:

```
<input name="acntName" type="text" class="form-control" readonly [(ngModel)]="AccountName">
```